# How can you use CSS to animate a rolling element across the screen repeatedly?

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

This is my first time asking a question on here and I've found questions that are somewhat similar, but haven't worked for my issue.

I am trying to spin a word across the screen from off-screen left to off-screen right. The center of the word should be it's rotation point (ie word spins in place from left side of screen to right). I have tried using variations of translateX and rotate, but it either rotates in place or moves left to right. When it does move from the left to right off the screen, it keeps extending the bounds of my screen and stretching it before it loops back to the left side. Any ideas how I can solve this? Seems simple, but I'm terrible with animations.

```
.move {
position: absolute;
animation: moveword 10s infinite linear;
}

.spin {
position: absolute;
animation: spin 7s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes spin {
    from {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

@keyframes moveword {
    from {
        left: -10%;
    }
    to {
        left: 95%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on code that you provide, I assume you could make something like this. 
`overflow: hidden` needs to be applied to separate element, not the `<body>` because it restricts scrolling.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.page {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.word {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  animation: word-anim 10s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes word-anim {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0px) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  
  70% {
    transform: translateX(70vw) rotateZ(360deg);
  }
  
  100% {
    transform: translateX(100vw) rotateZ(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <span class="word">A word</span>
</div>
```